# Parameterized Queries having IN clause not working as expected in blazer tool of ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blazer

Here is the example of MySQL connector based Blazer Query

```
SELECT * FROM customers where email_domain in ({domains})
```

When I pass ?domains=ibm.com it works however if I pass ?domains=ibm.com,ibm.co.in
Blazer modifies the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers where email_domain in ('ibm.com,ibm.co.in')
```

How can I pass parameter or variable to form the query correct as MYSQL doesn't support explode function to generate an array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE FIND_IN_SET(email_domain, {domains})
```